# Why git cheats with clean command?

Tags: git

we use git in our project.
git version 2.5.0
What can be cause for further confusing behavior?

```
git@ip5server:~$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    app/addons/arliteks/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
git@ip5server:~$ git clean -dn
Would remove app/addons/arliteks/
Would remove design/
Would remove js/
Would remove var/langs/en/
```

Why I don't see all 4 directories in first command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git does not track directories, only files. When you see a directory in `git status` output, it actually refers to the files *inside* that directory. A curious side effect is that an empty directory will never show in `git status`. Naturally, you cannot git-add a directory (well, you can, but it will add the files inside the directory, not the directory itself).

But when you do `git clean -dn`, the `-d` option means delete also the *untraked* directories. That is, directories with no tracked files inside.

To sum up, your first directory is non-empty. The other three are empty.

Comment: I understood the problem! Your answer isn't correct 100% but it is very close! The directories aren't empty, they contains hundred of files, but (!) the first directory didn't appear in my excludes file at all - this reason, why it appears in `git status`, others directories' **subdirectories** appear in my exclude file **but** didn't tracked (!). Other root directories which appears in exclude files without subdirectories aren't listed in git clean dn. So the solution is exclude the most top directory without listing some its' content in exclude file.

Comment: I was need it before, because we controlled some content of these directories.

Answer (score 0):

#### git clean

Checkout the difference between Capital X to lower x:

```
git clean -Xfd // capital X 
git clean -xfd // small x will remove all the
```

Read more about this clean command

> ***`-x`***  (Lower case)
>
> Don’t use the standard ignore rules **read from .gitignore** ... but do still use the ignore rules given with `-e` options.
>
> This allows removing all untracked files, including build products.
>
> This can be used (possibly in conjunction with git reset) to create a pristine working directory to test a clean build.
>
> ***`-X`***  (Upper case)

**Remove only files ignored by Git.**
This may be useful to rebuild everything from scratch, but keep manually created files.

Comment: Thanx for answer, but it still try delete some of excluded files... And I put your attansion, that it try delete _some_ of them, and other keeps.